# PyCharm Folder marked with red 'm' icon and "(<unnamed>)" - what does it mean?

Tags: pycharm

This is an issue I've not encountered before in many years of using PyCharm. I copied a folder from my file system into the project and the new folder was marked with a small red "m" icon and `(<unnamed>)` was appended to the folder name. Out of curiosity I created a new folder and copied the files into it - same issue. So I created a new folder and copied the files in small groups into it - this worked.

This is a folder for local resources; it's in `.gitignore`. I'm just curious why PyCharm is changing the directory name.

Answer (score 2):

From the PyCharm Help - Symbols Index, it appears that PyCharm sees that folder as containing a method, and it could be that it doesn't think that method has a name.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/symbols.html